# "Network Servers" folder mysteriously appeared on desktop, and cannot re-hide it?

Tags: directory

The "Network Servers" folder somehow ended up on my desktop, and I can't re-hide it, or otherwise remove it from the desktop area. There is likely a simple solution, but I don't know what it is. I also don't know where it came form or why it's there to beging with, although it may have popped up last night when I added a repository to download Arc themes as I don't recall it being there prior to yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unity tweak tool has this option under system>desktop icons>

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: This is the exact answer to my question, thank you!